# Error while using the Resizing layer in keras

Tags: keras, deep-learning, image-resizing, preprocessor

I am training a model where I have a dataset of different sizes of images, Now I am resizing all the images using the "Resizing" layer in keras inside my model

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Resizing(height=375, width=500, crop_to_aspect_ratio=True))
model.add(Rescaling(scale=1./255.))

model.add(
    Conv2D(40, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(375, 500, 3))
)
model.add(
    MaxPooling2D((2, 2))
)

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(300, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(30, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss = BinaryCrossentropy(), metrics=['accuracy'])

training = model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=10, validation_data = (test_images, test_labels))
```

I have tried removing the crop_to_aspect_ratio paramter and also converting the train and test images labels to numpy arrays, but nothing worked

Comment: You always need to include the error in the question, we cannot guess or assume what error you obtain.